# Classes of Lie groups with diagonalizable adjoints

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

$G$ is a Lie group, $\mathfrak{g}$ its Lie algebra and $ad_X$ the adjoint action at $X\in  \mathfrak{g}$.

I would like to know on what class of Lie groups all the $ad_X$ are diagonalizable. A similar question was already posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/912925/diagonalizabilty-of-adadjoint-map). The accepted answer provides an example where $ad_X$ is not diagonalisable and mentions the Jordan-Chevalley decomposition (I am not sure I understand its implications).

Questions:
-do such groups correspond to a well known class of Lie groups? (I gess not given the anwser of the post)
-what are the standard classes of Lie groups on which we diagonalize $ad_X$, for all $X$?

Thanks

Comment: This holds if $G$ is the product of a compact group and an abelian group; we can also take quotients of these. I don’t know if there are other examples.

Comment: The common wide class is that of tori (products of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$). They are the only nilpotent Lie groups with this property. Look at a course or a book on the classification of Lie groups, this is always treated.

Comment: This also should help you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toral_subalgebra : a toral algebra is always commutative

Comment: By "diagonalizable", you mean over $\mathbb C$ or over $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Torsten, I mean over $\mathbb{C}$.